# Event Binding Methods & Performance $(document).on("click", "#id", fn) VS $("#id").on("click", fn)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events, event-binding

Which one of following is better in terms of performance etc. and why?

```
1. `$(document).on("click", "#id", function (e) {   });` 
 
2. `$("#id").on("click", function (e) {   })`
   
3. `$("#id").die('click').live("click",function(e){ });`

4. `$("#id").live("click",function(e){ });`
```

What will be the effect on performance if we use event delegation? I am looking for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Throw away last two deprecated (and strange) versions. Then between first two - they are not the same, so should not be compared.

Comment: The first two have totally different purpose. Depends on how you manipulate the dom. 1. Dynamic Dom 2. Static Dom.

Comment: Both of them binds a click event for an element with id as ID.. I am in need of full explanation for all of them :-p

Comment: "I am in need of full explanation for all of them " - Then your question is far too broad for this site.

Comment: There is a [website](http://jsperf.com/) devoted to things like this. You should create a new perf review and then run it using several different browsers. If you want an explanation, you best bet is to read the documentation (they oftentimes provide some details there) or reading the source code and figuring out what differences are happening.

Comment: I was looking for a brief answer. I have read enough before posting this.

Comment: Thank You for http://jsperf.com/ link Brand :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLTR**
The explanation of all the above specified methods are given below.

1. `$(document).on("click", "#id", function (e) {   });`

This way of binding events, called `event delegation`, on the the document or a static parent element(say `body`) rather than to a particular specific element is done in case of dynamic DOM manipulation. A good example is that, think about a situation where you want to bind an event to a DOM element which may not be there when the page is loaded, but will be introduced into the DOM at a later stage by remote loading or by dynamic DOM manipulation. Your code won't be neat if you bind the events for newly introduced elements right after it is introduced in the DOM. So in such cases we use the above method to bind the events initially so that we don't have to worry whether the element is there or not while the binding happens. Here the click event is binded to the document and then delegated to the element specified. Since this is binded to the document or a static parent, the event propagation time will be more, i.e. **event propagation will be slow**, compared to the second method. `But this is the preferred way of doing it`.

2. `$("#id").on("click", function (e) {   })`

This kind of binding is used in cases where the DOM need not be static, but the element you specify has be present while you bind the event. Usually we do this in static DOM element cases. The only thing is that this kind of binding can be used only when that particular element onto which the event has to be binded is already present in the DOM. Since this is a direct binding and does not involve any delegation **event propagation will be fast** compared to method 1.

> Since the first kind of binding is done on the document, it will be
>   slow compared to the second one in which event is directly binded onto
>   the specific element.

3. `$("#id").die('click').live("click",function(e){ });` and
4. `$("#id").live("click",function(e){ });` have been deprecated in jQuery 1.7 
   and removed in jQuery 1.9.

> "Since all `.live()` events are attached at the document element,
>   events take the longest and slowest possible path before they are
>   handled."
>   - Quoted from https://api.jquery.com/live/.

This is answer for your question, which method is faster?

```
Method 2 > Method 1 > Method 3 & 4
```

But still `Method 1` is the preferred method.

Answer (score 2):

Please ignore the last two samples. Because those are dead. While coming to the first two samples, it could be decided based on the that context you are coding. First one is `event delegation`. so you can use it while dealing with elements which are created during run time. During the usage of event delegation, the immediate static parent must be provided in the place of `document` for enhanced performance. The second sample is a common one, but it cannot be incorporated while dealing with dynamic elements. May be you could use it after the insertion of dynamic elements into the `DOM`. But event delegation is preferred.

Comment: Is event delegation suggested for static DOM too.. What is the effect on perfommance..?

Comment: @MayankGupta There's no point in using event delegation over static dom elements. Since event delegation put a watch over event bubbling to trigger the event. There's no use in watching event bubbling while we using the static one.

Answer (score -3):

```
$(document).on("click", "#id", function (e) {   });
```

is ideally best

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: it is useful for dynamically created elements as well as static elements too :)

Comment: Any effect on performance.. Can you suggest a link where we can see what exactly happens inside as using event delegation event is created without element being there in DOM.

Comment: It's not the best. It's different. You can't say that the first better then the second, because they serve different purpose.

Comment: Consider adding more details on your answer, just saying particular is the best cannnot be considered as answer.

Comment: in Intel XDK(html5 mobile development sdk) docs clearly mentioned that event delegation increases performance and lessens chances of error which is need of mobile apps :)